# Why does the Base.match function return a SubString{String} type rather than just String in Julia?

Tags: julia

```
julia> s = "abcdefg"
"abcdefg"

julia> s1 = s[3:4]
"cd"

julia> s2 = match(r"c.", s).match
"cd"

julia> typeof(s)
String

julia> typeof(s1)
String

julia> typeof(s2)
SubString{String}
```

What functionality does `SubString` enable? It looks like a container. If so, what other types can it hold? If this is useful, why isn't `s1` a `SubString`?

I found this behavior strange when I had to convert `s2` into a pure `String` to get it into a `f(x::String)` function. What is the difference between using `String(s2)` and `string(s2)` for that conversion?

Comment: Most likely `f` should have been defined as `f(x::AbstractString)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SubString{String}` is just a `view` of `String`. `s1[3:4]` is not a `SubString` because it is `getindex` not `view` function (just like with arrays).

1. It is `SubString{String}` to avoid copying of data in the string, see e.g.:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> x = "a"^1_000_000;

julia> @btime $x[1:end];
  36.000 μs (1 allocation: 976.69 KiB)

julia> @btime @view $x[1:end];
  23.046 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

to note how much difference in allocations and speed it makes

2. In general you should avoid writing `s[3:4]` as it is not a safe indexing code (it is only safe if your string is ASCII which you can check with `isascii`). String indexing in Julia uses byte indices (not character indices)
3. `SubString{String}` has `String` parameter, as there are in general other string types than only `String`:

```
julia> using InlineStrings

julia> x = InlineString("abcd")
"abcd"

julia> typeof(x)
String7

julia> y = @view x[1:end]
"abcd"

julia> typeof(y)
SubString{String7}
```

4. As it is noted in comment by Antonello - most likely the `f` function should accept `AbstractString` and you would not even notice a problem.

All this is explained in https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/.

If you want something more hands-on check out for example chapter 6 of https://www.manning.com/books/julia-for-data-analysis (I do not want to do too much self promotion, but your question is one of the standard questions users ask and I explained all these topics in this chapter to address them).